# Comparing Strings in Address Lines

Tags: cognito-forms

I need to set `Address2.Line1 != Address.Line1` in the same form.

Originally, I had thought a simple reference to the input fields in a conditional would work, but the rule fails when testing; i.e., no matter what text is entered into the Address fields, a custom error always shows.

Looking through Cognito Form's guides, I do not see supported options for CHAR arrays or other variables that can take "Address.Line" references rather than specifically enter text.

Best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. Can you provide us with an example of what you are looking to do, and what your use case is in our Support Request(https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/)?

Comment: According to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging force tags into the title should be avoided.

Comment: I have a form that requires 2 full addresses: 1 Permanent and 1 Local.
Permanent cannot equal Local and vice versa.

Comment: I just submitted a Support Request. No case # assigned yet.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am not trying to use tags, nor is it involving a title area. Only address fields need be compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Cognito Forms Support:

=(Address.Line1 = Address2.Line1) or (Address.City = Address2.City) or (Address.PostalCode = Address2.PostalCode) or (Address.State = Address2.State)